# Who was the sovereign of the lowest title?

Tags: feudalism, titles

It is known that there existed sovereign `counts` (Armagnac, count at God will). But had you read about sovereign `viscounts` or `barons`? Or some `boyar`/`boyarin` (~= baron) in Eastern Europe?

The same about some Viking titles. Eric the Red was the sovereign of Greenland, being an `earl`, for example. Were anywhere some sovereign `bonds`?

On the East, `emirs` and `khans` had sovereignty often, and I hadn't heard about sovereign `beks` or `noyons`?

Again: What was the lowest known title of an independent ruler in Western European, Eastern European, Muslim or Mongol systems. AFAIK, the lowest titles that happened to be sovereign are: count, knjaz(prince), emir, khan. Can you lower one or more of these positions?

Another system with its own *lowest possible independent ruler* will be appreciated, too.

Edit.
As a sovereign/idependent ruler, I propose to consider one who:

1. has no permanent limitation to his will from without the state. Of course, any state agreement limits the will of the ruler, but these agreements are not permanent. 100000 marks debt does not make a  ruler dependent, but permanent yearly payment of 1 mark a day is a dependency.
2. The only important limitations are those that are considered serious and that cannot be broken without seriously damaging the state. (serious from the point of view of that ruler)
3. The limitations set by commons or gentry juridical bodies are considered irrelevant for the question.
4. Religious matters are irrelevant for the question.
5. Of course, the question of the power transition should belong to the state.

Point 2 is not up to the medieval understanding of sovereignty, but I voluntarily weakened the principle in this point for not to overlook any early parlamentarian states.

<sub>Beware wikipedia: in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_nobility it says that noyon was the title just below the Khagan, but no, Batu was just below `Khagan`, and he was `khan` - that was the title between `khagan` and `noyon`.</sub>

Comment: Since a baron was by definition a tenant-in-chief of the sovereign, I don't see how there could have been a sovereign baron.

Comment: You need to define these terms better. Greenland was never sovereign (it is still a part of Denmark, after it was taken from Norway in 1814). I guess the answer to this question would be something like a tribal chief somewhere. I wonder what the Andaman islanders call their supreme authority.

Comment: if you do not restrict yourself to european nobility: every time a european nation signed a treaty with a tribe without demanding submission, they would recognize a tribal chief as sovereign (even if it is not a country in the european sense). You could also argue that north african barbary coast beys were quasi-sovereigns in the periods when ottoman rule was nominal. Another quasi-sovereign small title would be the Protos of Mount Athos. BTW: does any bishopric also counts? Bishops are on a different title hierarchy.

Comment: @Luiz 1. They didn't have titles before that agreement and after it they were not sovereign :-). 2. In Early and middle feudal times North Africa was far more civilized than barbaric Europe. And they were sovereign emirs I mentioned before. We cannot place "bey" in the feudal staircase - these states had more modern, more flat system of titles - sovereign(bey) and... No more nobles! Gentry without nobility.  ... Bishops are interesting, some German ones were independent, but were they independent inside the Church? I don't know.

Comment: Not all agreements mean submission, and tribal chief is a title (outside of european nobility). There were pagans tribes in early medieval europe: Germans, Vikings, Pomeranians, Frisians, Lithuanians, the Rus/slavic peoples  before conversion, Alans, Cumans and other asian nomadic invaders. Look for the many dealings and peace treaties with the baltic tribal pagans before the baltic crusades, or when they had to buy vikings or pagan raiders off. And a catholic bishop could claim temporal sovereignty, he would not be a vassal of the pope, spiritual jurisdiction is other matter.

Comment: @Luiz chief is not a feudal title, so it is out of the feudal staircase of titles. As for early feudal pagan Northern and Eastern Europe, I will gladly accept any answer. But they HAD the sequence of titles, maybe not so long as in Germany/France. As for bishops, I mean not the faith dependence, but the taxation one.

Comment: @Gangnus [Moshoeshoe I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshoeshoe_I) Was a tribal chief in a feudal society.  He dealt directly with Queen Victoria, which led to [Basutoland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basutoland) becoming a British protectorate, ultimately retaining much of that feudal society (he became _Paramount Chief_) under the direct authority of the Queen.

Comment: @sempaiscuba So, he was not a sovereign ruler. The British Empire had no sovereign rulers under itself, the same way as the Russian Empire, and in contrast to the German Empire.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Holy German Empire was meant, of course.

Comment: @Gangnus I meant that he was a sovereign ruler _before_ signing the treaty with Victoria. That was acknowledged in the letters exchanged between Moshoeshoe and Victoria.  However, I'm not sure if he qualifies under your criteria (mainly because I don't think I understand the scope of the question).

Comment: @sempaiscuba He was a ruler, but without a feudal title. He simply didn't belong to either of Western European or Eastern European or Muslim or Nomade systems. So, we cannot compare his *position* to their *titles*.

Comment: @Gangnus Like I said, I don't think the scope of the question is clear.  But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @sempaiscuba 1. I tried to reformulate the question at the bottom. 2. I am not fixing on the Europe, because I deeply dislike eurocentrism. It is the blindness for historical thinking.

Comment: @TomasBy: Greenland was sovereign for roughly 300 years, from when the last Viking settlement collapsed around 1400 until the Danes asserted possession again in the 16th century.

Comment: @Gangnus For me it is totally obscure, what you mean with souvereign. This is a concept for Europe from 17th century on. If "reichsunmittelbare Territorien" (imperial immediat territories, there were even villages) in the HRE are souvereign is not clear. If tribes in the "new world" are, too.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I don't think that is how the Norwegian/Danish kings at the time looked at it. Also, "uninhabited" is not the same as "sovereign".

Comment: @K-HB: sovereign = "free to govern itself; completely independent". So the tribes probably were but not the HRE villages.

Comment: @Gangnus the chief was a sovereign ruler until he decided to cede that sovereignty to the Queen.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens 1450-982 = ~470 years. Where had you found 300?

Comment: @K-HB Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereignty. That is what I mean.

Comment: @jwenting Before he ceded his sovereignty he had not a feudal title. After that his position is irrelevant. I had already explained that two times on this page.

Comment: @Gangnus I'm sure he had one according to his own culture and language. You're deliberately cherrypicking things and redefining them as you go in order to get the answer you desire it seems.

Comment: @jwenting His culture does not relate to the question. You haven't even read it and either are not trying to understand or simply are unable to, because You hate that I do not focus on the W.Europe. And for me those "historians" not noticing 19/20 of the world are uninteresting.

Comment: @Gangnus you're the one singlemindedly focusing on western Europe here, in not taking the equivalents to western European titles into account when considering whether people held a position of power within their own societies.

Comment: I cannot support re-open without addressing the issues that forced closure. Reading the extensive comment string (always a danger sign), I note two things - first that the concept of sovereign is clear to @Gangnus, but apparently less clear to everyone else, and that the clarifications in the comment string have not been edited into the question.  I recommend revising the question to incorporate the information in the comment string, and citing a very clear definition of sovereign.

Comment: I propose to move all the comments to chat; I think the revisions to the comment make the chat less relevant _the the current formulation_ of the question.

Comment: @Gangnus When you say "_Before he ceded his sovereignty he had not a feudal title_" about an African Chief like Moshoeshoe I, would that also hold true for a Clan Chief in the Scottish Highlands?  That was very definitely a feudal society, and "_Chief_" was very definitely a feudal title within that society.

Answer (score 1):

The [ranking of German nobility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_nobility#Reigning_titles) place [*Burgrave*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgrave#Holy_Roman_Empire_territories) equivalent to the [English *Viscount*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graf#Burgrave_/_Viscount). In the Holy Roman Empire the holders of this title were *Imperial Princes*, and thus sovereign.

> There were four hereditary burgraviates ranking as principalities within the Holy Roman Empire, those of [*Antwerp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antwerp#16th_century), [*Magdeburg*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magdeburg#History), [*Freidburg*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedberg,_Hesse#History), and [*Nuremberg*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgraviate_of_Nuremberg). The [Burgrave of Meissen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_burgraves_of_Meissen) was hereditary but not entitled to the privileges of an [Imperial Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princes_of_the_Holy_Roman_Empire) in the H.R.E.

The [four unique titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graf#Rhinegrave,_Wildgrave,_Raugrave,_Altgrave) of [Rhinegrave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheingau), [Waldgrave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waldgrave), [Raugrave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raugrave), and [Altgrave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_Salm) were equivalent in prestige and privilege to Burgrave, but acquired unique titles prior to the creation of the more generic Burgrave title.

Here are the [rankings of the nobility and sovereigns of the Holy Roman Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_nobility#Reigning_titles).

[image]

Note that there are many more then we are accustomed to in the English and British peerages. The main equivalencies, in descending order, are:

- *Duke* (British, ruler of a *duchy*) to *Herzog* (German, ruler of a *Herzogtum*)
- *Marquess* (British, ruler of a *march*) to *Margraf* (German, ruler of a *Markgrafschaft*)
- *Earl* (British, ruler of a *county*) to *Reichsgraf* (German, ruler of a *Grafschaft*)
- *Viscount* (British) to *Burgraf* (German, ruler of a *Burgraviate*)
- *Baron* (British, ruler of a barony) to *Reichsfreiherr* (German, ruler of a *Freiherrschaft*)
- *Baronet* (British, no land) to [*Ritter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritter) (German, no land)

Comment: @TomasBy: One must take care in translating from the German to the English. If one translates the German "*graf*" as a generic "*count*" then yes, all Margraves, Landgraves, Burgraves, plain Grafs, and others are, generically, "*counts*". However this distinction really means only subsidiary to the Duke of a "*stem duchy*"; there remains a pecking order with Margraves for instance, as the "*Count of a Mark*", being equivalent to an English *marquess* ruling a *march*. The *Burgraves* were likewise vice-counts, equivalent to a *viscount*.

Comment: Excellent! I was absolutely sure that because viscount IS vice-count, it cannot be sovereign, but you had found so interesting workaround through equal titles. Only... Excuse me, viscount is a French title. Taken by English, yes.

Comment: Yes. Margrave=Marquees > Count. Counts of a mark had some important piece of land with additional power, usually to keep the border against some constant enemy. Moravia - against Hungarians, for example, or Breton Mark - against Bretons.

Comment: Sorry, but, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgrave, burgraves were NOT below counts, rather ABOVE them. The fact that their title goes from castellan, as viscounts, does not mean they are on the same level.. :-(

Comment: #Pieter Geerkens  Rulers of principalities within the Holy Roman Empire were not sovereign, except to the degree that States and tribal government within the USA are sovereign. Principalities within the HRE were dependent governments like states or Indian tribes, not independent governments like China or the USA.  Thus they were not sovereign.

Comment: @MAGolding I think they (or some of them) were, e.g. Kingdom of Bavaria, Kingdom of Bohemia, the electors, free Hanseatic cities etc.

Comment: @TomasBy +1. Absolutely. Only Bavaria for almost 1000 years long of feudal times was not a kingdom, but duchy/Herzogtum.

Comment: @MAGolding: By at least the 1500 the *Imperial Princes* of the H.R.E. absolutely had sovereignty. They could mint their own coins, make their own treaties (even with the emperor) and maintain their own armies. The most resounding evidence that they were regarded by other royal houses as *royal* and not *noble* is that they were regarded as suitable matches for those *royal* houses.

Comment: @TomasBy: Napoleon grants the title of King to Bavaria after 1805 when the H.R.E. is dissolved. Bohemia is a personal possession of the Habspurgs by the end of the period. It was grandfathered in as a kingdom from 1198.

Comment: @TomasBy: I have absolutely no idea what your last comment is attempting to say.

Comment: @TomasBy: Read the precise definition under [Imperial Princes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princes_of_the_Holy_Roman_Empire#Definition). There were hundreds such by the late Medieval Period - most obviously quite small.

Comment: Sorry, and where from is that table? For the wiki page says vice versa and it has references. And you are referencing that very page, too.

Comment: @MAGolding depends on the era. For much of the HREs existence the states within it had a similar level of independence as the countries of the current EU do have now. So unless you claim that (and I admit there is grounds to do so) the Netherlands or Denmark are not sovereign nations, the nations making up the HRE were indeed sovereign even if not wholly independent.

Comment: @Jwenting.  One difference is that EU members are formally independent and have the legal right to withdraw from the EU, while principalities in the HRE were formally dependent and princes could be condemned by the Emperor and the Diet and have their principalities confiscated, as happened to the Duke of Montferrat and Modena in 1708, for example.

Comment: @MAGolding: What do you think the European Court is if not a modern version of the Imperial Diet? Read the Treaties of Augsburg and Munster.